# Speed-up SQL Insert Statements

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server-2008

I am facing an issue with an ever slowing process which runs every hour and inserts around 3-4 million rows daily into an SQL Server 2008 Database.

The schema consists of a large table which contains all of the above data and has a clustered index on a datetime field (by day), a unique index on a combination of fields in order to exclude duplicate inserts, and a couple more indexes on 2 varchar fields.

The typical behavior as of late, is that the insert statements get suspended for a while before they complete. The overall process used to take 4-5 mins and now it's usually well over 40 mins.

The inserts are executed by a .net service which parses a series of xml files, performs some data transformations and then inserts the data to the DB. The service has not changed at all, it's just that the inserts take longer than they use to.

At this point I'm willing to try everything. Please, let me know whether you need any more info and feel free to suggest anything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By insert, you do mean "append" and there is absolutely no updating going on. And I assume you mean 3-4 million rows was the standard insert and has not changed.

Comment: Also if this is adding 3-4 million rows per day. Is anything being purged or is the data size just growing?

Comment: This doesn't seem surprising, the more data you have in the table, the larger your unique index index will be, therefore the longer it will take read and check to ensure there are no duplicates in the data being inserted. You also have to update all indexes after the insert has completed which will be taking longer the more data is in there.

Comment: In addition, since your clustered index is on a datetime field, if you are not inserting only new data (i.e. all datetimes being inserted are newer than the last datetime in the table), your index will be getting increasingly fragmented.

Comment: thanks for all you comments, I do mean appending new data and yes, the datetimes being inserted are actually timestamps so they are incremental in nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have exhausted the buffer pools ability to cache all the pages needed for the insert process. Append-style inserts (like with your date table) have a very small working set of just a few pages. Random-style inserts have basically the entire index as their working set. If you insert a row at a random location the existing page that row is supposed to be written to must be read first.

This probably means tons of disk seeks for inserts.

Make sure to insert all rows in one statement. Use bulk insert or TVPs. This allows SQL Server to optimize the query plan by sorting the inserts by key value making IO much more efficient.

This will, however, not realize a big speedup (I have seen 5x in similar situations). To regain the original performance you must bring the working set back into memory. Add RAM, purge old data, or partition such that you only need to touch very few partitions.

Comment: the only resource that seems to be peeking while inserting is disk usage. other than that RAM and CPU usage is very-very low

Comment: How did you assess RAM usage? (I honestly do not trust your observation here and want to make sure it is right.) How big is the table's clustered index in GB and how much memory did you configure for SQL Server? Do not use the Taskmanager values, they are misleading.

Comment: I only have task manager values to go with. The allocated RAM is 10GB.

Comment: Well, find out how big the table is. Also find the index sizes. You can right-click on the database and choose Reports->Disk Usage by Partition. What did you set as max server memory and how much RAM does the server have?

Answer (score 1):

drop index's before insert and set them up on completion

Comment: After 3 years he'll have 900m rows. You usually don't drop such indexes for 3-4m inserts. Far too expensive. Also, that makes the process offline.

Comment: that isn't an option. the recreation of the indexes will simple take ages to complete

Comment: The process of dropping / creating index's results in a whole order of magnitude speed up for very large inserts, that's including the recreation of the index. Also you may not need to remove all index's, dropping a few can have a dramatic result.